# Python append entry KeyError problem because of missing data from the API

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

So, i'm trying to collect data from an API to make a dataframe. The problems is that that when i get the response in JSON some of the values are missing for some rows. That means that one row has all 10 out of 10 values and some only have 8 out of 10.
For e.g. I have such code to fill in the data from the API to then form a DataFrame:

```
response = r.json()
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
l = []
for entry in response:
    l.append([
        entry['realizationreport_id'],
        entry['suppliercontract_code'],
        entry['rid'],
        entry['ppvz_inn'],
```

I get this error because in one of the rows the API didn't give a value in response:

```
KeyError: 'ppvz_inn'
```

So i'm tryng to fix it so that the cell of the DataFrame is filled with 0 or Nan if the API doesn't have a value for this specific row

```
l = []
for entry in response:
    l.append([
        entry['realizationreport_id'],
        entry['suppliercontract_code'],
        entry['rid'],
        entry['ppvz_inn'],
        try:
          entry['ppvz_supplier_name'],
        except KeyError:
            '0',
```

And now i get this error:

```
try:
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to actually make it work and fill those cells with no data?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a `try-except` statement in the middle of your `append` statement.

You could either work with `if` statements or first try to fix your JSON data by filling in empty values. You could also maybe use `setdefault`, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_setdefault.asp) some info about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.defaultdict`. It's a subclass of dict which does not return KeyError, creating a called key instead.
You can cast your existing dict to defaultdict using unpacking.

```
for entry in response:
  entry_defaultdict = defaultdict(list, **entry)
```

In this case, every call to non-existing object will create an empty list as a value of the key.